# Getting Error when uploading xml file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload file to Google Cloud Storage, However I am getting an error like:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull
```

The Format of xml file which I want to upload on Google Cloud Storage:

```
<set xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

File and Google Bucket, where I want to upload file to bucket.

String fileName = "data.xml"

String fileBucket = "upload-file";

```
 public static void uploadFile(String fileName, String fileBucket)
            throws IOException {
        final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
                .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
                .retryMaxAttempts(10)
                .totalRetryPeriodMillis(50000)//15000
                .build());
        gcsService.createOrReplace(
                new GcsFilename(fileBucket, fileName),
                new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("application/xml")
                        .acl("public-read")
                        .cacheControl("public, max-age=0").build());
    }
```

Getting Error as following:

```
Jan 29, 2019 6:49:31 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions$Builder.checkNotEmpty(GcsFileOptions.java:252)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions$Builder.mimeType(GcsFileOptions.java:173)
    at com.vivoiz.healofy.backend.v2.helpers.utils.AppUtilities.uploadFileToGCS(AppUtilities.java:168)
    at com.vivoiz.healofy.backend.v2.apis.InternalApis.uploadFile(InternalApis.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:351)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher.dispatch(PathDispatcher.java:50)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
INFO     2019-01-29 06:49:31,105 module.py:861] v2: "GET /_ah/api/internalapis/v1/uploadFile HTTP/1.1" 503 454
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It seems that conflicting libraries are there. Would you share your dependencies? (pom.xml or build.gradle) Especially the Google Cloud Storage library and Guava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file to the Google Cloud Storage, you need the `StorageOptions` services. You can see the documentation about [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java).

This will upload the `Hello, Cloud Storage!` string to a file called `blob_name` in the bucket called `bucket`. You just change the names accordingly to your project's needs.

To upload one of your local files. Create a function that will read the file's data and returns them to your main function that will upload the data to the bucket.

I did a little bit of coding myself and the following code, uploaded the file with the data that you are mentioning above, successfully.

---

**The function that reads the file:**

It will read the file form the local storage e.g. Cloud Shell and it will return all the data.

```
private String readFile(){
      // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "PATH/TO/THE/FILE/THAT/IS/GOING/TO/BE/UPLOADED/FILE_NAME/xml";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;
        // This will be the full file after reading
        String output = "";

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                output = output + line;
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                output = output + "Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'";         
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println( 
                output = output + "Error reading file '" + fileName + "'";         
        }

      return output;
  }
```

---

**The upload function:**

It will use all the data that it will read from the file and uploaded them to a new file in the bucket. The difference between the documentation code is in line where `...readFile().getBytes(UTF_8)...` is called. Instead of the string we add the function that is going to return all the data for upload.

```
public String uploadFile(){

        String bucket_name = "BUCKET_NAME";
        String file_name = "PATH/TO/WHERE/THE/FILE/WILL/BE/UPLOADED/FILE_NAME.xml"

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket_name, file_name);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, readFile().getBytes(UTF_8));
}
```

Comment: I follow the same steps, now I am getting error like:  `XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: Line Number 1, Column 1:Unable to open file 'https://storage.googleapis.com/<BucketName/<question.xml>` This is the file which I want to read and upload to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: The code that I have provided, works only when you want to upload a file from **Local Storage** to a **Bucket** in `Google Cloud Storage`.

The error you are getting, specifies that you are trying to access and read a file from an Google Cloud Storage bucket. In this case the approach is going to be different.

Can you please verify to me where this file, that you are trying to read, is stored? Are you trying to copy the file from one Google Cloud Storage bucket to another one?